# Cannot Write To The Output File The Spcified Path/FileName Are Too Long?

Tags: c#, filenames

I got this error in one of my projects seemingly out of no where:

> ```
> Cannot write to the output file "obj\Debug 
> \WindowsFormsApplication1.Properties.Resources.resources".
>
> The specified path, file name, or both are too long.  
> The fully qualified file name must be less than 260 characters, 
> and the directory name must be less than 248 characters.
> ```

How can I fix this?

Comment: What's the absolute path of that directory?

Comment: It's almost certainly down to the depth of your path to the file, move your project folder closer to the root of the drive.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a shorter path, Win32 doesn't support longer paths than that. Shorter directory-names or less deeply nested hierarchies could help. The path to where you're project files are is already so long, so that when it tries to generate a file in the debug subdirectory the maximal length for paths is exceeded.

NTFS itself, the native NT APIs and the Win32 API using the `\\?\` support much longer paths. But for "normal" path Win32 is limited to 260 chars for historical reasons. In particular C programs rely on the fact that a 260 char buffer can contain any path. The part of Microsoft responsible for the Win32 API is very careful not to break compatibility with older programs.

Answer (score 1):

I assume the "\obj.." directory is in some deep path, so the fix would be to move it so it doesn't exceed the 260/248 length limit.